# Dynamic-sized iframe in between two static-sized columns (3 column layout)

Tags: html, css, iframe

The layout I'm looking for is one static-length column on the left, one static-length column on the right, and the middle column stretching to fit the remaining space. So the column on the left and right should stay the same size regardless of resizing. Each of these columns is its own div element, I'll put the code below. How can I get this to work? The problem is that the iframe does not stretch to fit the remaining width given. Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<div id="LeftColumn"></div>
<iframe id="ifrm"></div>
<div id="RightColumn"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
iframe#ifrm {
    position: fixed;
    top: 3px;
    left: 210px;
    right: 140px;
    height: 98%;
}

div#LeftColumn {
    padding: 3px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #494949;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    width: 200px;
    height: 97.5%;
}

div#RightColumn {
    position: fixed;
    right: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #494949;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    width: 140px;
    height: 98%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you don't appear to have an opening `<div>` containing your iframe.

Once that's in place, you can position your iframe div relative to the other two and simply maximize the iframe inside that container.

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EhLuX/1/).

Comment: The </div> at the end was actually a typo on my part - I had closed the iframe tag. But your suggestion worked, thanks!